# imagemagick error on node.js

Tags: node.js, imagemagick, npm

I'm getting error like this

```
    node.js:201
        throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick
              ^
Error: Command failed: CreateProcessW: The system cannot find the file specified
.

    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\imagemagic
k\imagemagick.js:64:15)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:70:17)
    at maybeExit (child_process.js:361:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (child_process.js:466:7)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:67:17)
    at Array.0 (net.js:320:10)
    at EventEmitter._tickCallback (node.js:192:40)
```

image paths are fine & operations are on node v0.6.11 & Imagemagick v0.1.2

any idea abt problem

Comment: It looks like it can't find the imagemagick executable. Are you supplying an absolute path?

Comment: @LinusGThiel I given Absolute path & IM exists

Comment: What happens if you start the node REPL and issue the command: `require('fs').statSync(PATH_TO_IM)`?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this reply helps someone else...
I edited identify.path and convert.path and worked

```
var img = require('imagemagick');
im.identify.path = "C:/Program Files/ImageMagick-6.8.2-Q16/identify";
im.convert.path = "C:/Program Files/ImageMagick-6.8.2-Q16/convert";
```

I don't know if there are a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that ImageMagic is installed and available within the environment path. Try to use it from the commandline first, and do the operation yourself, not by using any other node modules.

If it works fine then you can use the `child_process.exec()` API like this:

```
var util = require('util'),
    exec = require('child_process').exec,
    child;

child = exec('cat *.js bad_file | wc -l',
  function (error, stdout, stderr) {
    console.log('stdout: ' + stdout);
    console.log('stderr: ' + stderr);
    if (error !== null) {
      console.log('exec error: ' + error);
    }
});
```

For more information. Check this [Process and Forking API in Node.JS](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/child_processes.html).

One more thing. Don't forget to quote the paths that has spaces and special chars in them before passing them in the command line. This will save you lots of headache and bug hunting.

With the little information you provide this is all I can answer. That's why the answer is not exactly specific to your case. If you need more from this website (SO) you should at least provide enough code and even better complete (i.e. runnable) code that contains only the problematic part.

Answer (score 0):

Did you already isolate the error to a specific codeline?

If not, ok, we got little bit of information for debugging:

> The system cannot find the file specified

You already may have a glitch where the problem could be, so go through all I/O operations and try to eliminate one by one. Debug with `console.log` or your favourite method to find your way through.